# La consola me da un error pero no entiendo bien porque

Tags: java, compilador, lenguaje-compilado

el código es este:

```
package ejerciciosentrega2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejerc18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserte una cadena de caracteres");
        int contador=0;
        String cadena=entrada.nextLine();

          char[] Arraycadena=cadena.toCharArray();

          for(int i=0; i<Arraycadena.length;i++) {
              char caracter=Arraycadena[i];

              for(int e=0; e<Arraycadena.length;i++) {
                  if(Arraycadena[e]==Arraycadena[i]) {
                      contador++;
                  }
              }
              System.out.println(Arraycadena[i]+""+ contador);
              contador=0;

          }




    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>     at ejerciciosentrega2.ejerc18.main(ejerc18.java:19)

Y eso de ahí arriba es el error que me da después de compilarlo. Necesito ayuda, no entiendo que ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo esta intentando entrar a un indice no declarado

Tu primer `for` esta bien formulado, pero el segundo tiene un error.

```
  for(int i=0; i<Arraycadena.length;i++) {
      char caracter=Arraycadena[i];

      for(int e=0; e<Arraycadena.length;i++) {
```

Fijate que en el segundo for estas incrementando a `i`, que es el iterador de tu primer `for`, es por ello que entras en un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`,

Tú codigo quedaría asi:

```
package ejerciciosentrega2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ejerc18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Inserte una cadena de caracteres");
        int contador=0;
        String cadena=entrada.nextLine();

          char[] Arraycadena=cadena.toCharArray();

          for(int i=0; i<Arraycadena.length;i++) {
              char caracter=Arraycadena[i];

              for(int e=0; e<Arraycadena.length;e++) {
                  if(Arraycadena[e]==Arraycadena[i]) {
                      contador++;
                  }
              }
              System.out.println(Arraycadena[i]+""+ contador);
              contador=0;

          }




    }

}
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.